# Como atualizar a foto do chat mais rapidamente?

Tags: suporte, chat

Notei que as foto e nome quando atualizada no perfil leva um tempo a mais para ser atualizada no chat, é possível adiantar esse processo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primeiro é necessário atualizar na comunidade que deseja, para isto acesse este link:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/<seu id>
```

Então faça o upload da nova foto:

> [image: upload]

Se já tiver feito agora deve ir até o perfil do chat no seu nome no topo:

> [image: chat perfil]

Ou acesse este link:

```
https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/<seu id no chat>
```

> Note que o `id` do chat **não é o mesmo** do site

Então ao chegar na tela clique em <kbd>[change]</kbd> como na imagem:

> [image: link para troca de profile no chat]

Então no campo digite o nome do site que prefere usar como perfil:

> [image: campo "select profile" no chat]

No caso se usou atualizou a foto do `pt.stackoverflow.com` então digite:

> pt.stack

Que deve aparecer o `Stack Overflow em Português`, então clique nele e o perfil irá atualizar:

> [image: selecionar comunidade]

Em seguida a imagem irá atualizar